# Fetching huge data from Oracle in Python

Tags: python, oracle, file, cx-oracle

I need to fetch huge data from Oracle (using cx_oracle) in python 2.6, and to produce some csv file.

The data size is about 400k record x 200 columns x 100 chars each.

Which is the best way to do that?

Now, using the following code...

```
ctemp = connection.cursor()
ctemp.execute(sql)
ctemp.arraysize = 256
for row in ctemp:
  file.write(row[1])
  ...
```

... the script remain hours in the loop and nothing is writed to the file... (is there a way to print a message for every record extracted?)

Note: I don't have any issue with Oracle, and running the query in SqlDeveloper is super fast.

Thank you, gian

Comment: "Is there a way to print a message"....yes, add a print statement to your code...

Comment: Do you have any `file.flush()` or similar in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cur.fetchmany()` instead.
It will fetch chunk of rows defined by arraysise (256)

Python code:

```
def chunks(cur): # 256
    global log, d
    while True:
        #log.info('Chunk size %s' %  cur.arraysize, extra=d)
        rows=cur.fetchmany()

        if not rows: break;
        yield rows
```

Then do your processing in a for loop;

```
for i, chunk  in enumerate(chunks(cur)):
            for row in chunk:
                     #Process you rows here
```

That is exactly how I do it in my [TableHunter for Oracle](https://github.com/alexbuz/TableHunter-For-Oracle/blob/master/table_hunter.py).

Answer (score 0):

- add print statements after each line
- add a counter to your loop indicating progress after each N rows
- look into a module like 'progressbar' for displaying a progress indicator

Comment: Have you heard of [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)? Much better than using `print`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is asking the database for the data one row at the time which might explain the slowness.

Try:

```
ctemp = connection.cursor()
ctemp.execute(sql)
Results = ctemp.fetchall()
for row in Results:
    file.write(row[1])
```

Comment: Fetch 800 megabytes into memory first, then write to file? Could work, but I'd rather not.