# Fetchmany() loop to write in to multiple files

Tags: python

I have 1000 records that I would like to loop through in chunks of 100 and write to multiple files. The below code creates the same set of data in all the files.

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@db')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY CREATION_TIME')
result = curs.fetchmany(100)
items = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in curs.description], row)) for row in result]
for i in range(10):
    with open('C:\\Users\\Output%i.json' % i, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump({'items': items}, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False, default=default)
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how would i loop it in such a way that the data is chunked in 100's in multiple files until there are no more rows.

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818751/7540911)?

Comment: What is `for i in range(10):` for? Why are you splitting 100 rows by 10?

Comment: You are only fetching once, so of course you are writing the same data over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `curs.fetchmany()` in a loop, not put a loop after fetching 100 rows.

```
i = 0
while True:
    result = curs.fetchmany(100)
    if len(result) == 0:
        break:
    items = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in curs.description], row)) for row in result]
    with open('C:\\Users\\Output%i.json' % i, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump({'items': items}, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False, default=default)
    i += 1
```